# Specifying remote directories to be excluded from rsnapshot backup

Tags: rsync, rsnapshot

I've looked around a bit without finding an exact answer to my question, which is how to specify a directory to be excluded from only the remote filesystem backup.

Say I've got two machines: a desktop (server) and a laptop. My home directory on each of them is `/home/tom`. `rsnapshot` lives on the desktop (`localhost`) with its config file(s). The `backup` commands, therefore, are:

```
backup /home/tom/ localhost/
backup tom@laptop:/home/tom/ laptop/
```

All well and good. But say I've got `/home/tom/music` on the laptop. It's stuff copied over from the desktop, and large. But when I go to exclude `/home/tom/music/` from only the backup of `tom@laptop`:

```
exclude tom@laptop:/home/tom/music/
```

But this doesn't result in `music/` being excluded, and causes my herpes to flare up.

Doing this:

```
exclude /home/tom/music/
```

of course causes `music/` to be excluded from both the `localhost` and `laptop` backups, and causes my PID to flare up.

My solution for now is to simply have separate `rsnapshot` config files for each host, and execute `rsnapshot` once for each host. But this shouldn't be necessary.

So how would I exclude a directory from only the remote (laptop) backup?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a fourth field for the `backup` line, which can be used for such tasks. So your line should look like follows.

```
backup tom@laptop:/home/tom/ laptop/ exclude=/home/tom/music
```

You can add more per `backup` options by separating these with a comma. For further reading consult the `man` page of `rsnapshot`.

Comment: It might be helpful to know the syntax for adding other excluded directories. Are they comma-separated, or is the "exclude=..." phrase simply repeated with each value?

Comment: it's comma, and the output will show u exclude=

Answer (score 8):

Since this is the top result for my google search, I think the following might help others too:

[Thomas' command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/344363/100397) works, but it removes all globally defined *exclude* directives in /etc/rsnapshot.conf

In order to **keep** existing *excludes* you can use the following

```
backup tom@laptop:/home/tom/ laptop/ +rsync_long_args=--exclude=/home/tom/music
```

Comment: Thanks. I believe this effect reared its ugly head causing me to abort my attempt to use a single rsnapshot config. Maybe now I'll try doing it right.

Answer (score 1):

Note the equals sign in [Thomas' example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/344363/100397). If you miss it, `rsnapshot configtest` fails with an error suggesting you use tabs!

You also don't need to prefix the `exclude=` with a plus, as some other Q&As suggest -- and if you do, `rsnapshot configtest` will fail with 'uninitialized value in concatenation or string'.

Here's an example with multiple excludes:

```
[..]
exclude    /foo1
exclude    /foo2
[..]
backup    /from    /to    exclude=/bar,exclude=/baz
```

Note also that excludes starting with slash *are relative to the backup root* (i.e., relative to $snapshot_root/from) and NOT relative to the server root. That's surprised a lot of posters!

Comment: To whoever edited this answer to say "pluses are a good idea": adding a plus causes configtest to fail. Your edit edited accordingly.